# PHP Email Form Formatting

Tags: php, email, format

I have, with the help of a few users here - created a form that sends data (name, checkbox awnsers) to my email.

However, when I recieve the email it is wrongly formatted and thus not very useful to me.

My code is below:

**PHP (mailer.php)**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "myemail@email.com";
$subject = "This is the subject";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$match_name= $_POST['match_name'];

$check_msg ="";
foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) {
$check_msg .= "Selected: $value\n";
}

$body = "From: $name_field\n $check_msg";
$body = "Match: $match_name\n $check_msg"; 

mail($to, $subject, $body);
echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";

} else {
echo "blarg!";
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>World Cup Challenge</title>
<style>
BODY{color:#000000; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Verdana}
.button {background-color: rgb(128,128,128); color:#ffffff; font-size: 8pt;}
.inputc {font-size: 8pt;}
.style3 {font-size: xx-small}
</style>
</head>

<form method="POST" action="mailer.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" size=""><br>
<br>

Brazil VS Croatia
<input type="hidden" name="match_name" value="Brazil VS Croatia"> 
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Brazil">Brazil<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Croatia">Croatia<br>
<br>

Mexico VS Cameroon
<input type="hidden" name="match_name" value="Mexico VS Cameroon"> 
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Mexico">Mexico<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Cameroon">Cameroon<br>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Some background, I am creating this form for myself and a few friends to select our picks for the upcoming World Cup. I will need there to be 50 matches posted, that they can select their choice for each.

When i recieve the email, I want it to be formatted as:

```
**NAME OF USER** 

MATCH NAME 
SELECTED TEAM

NAME NAME #2 
SELECTED TEAM
```

and so forth, this script currently works - but just formats wrongfully. (forgive me if I formatted wrong, or for my newbie-ness)

any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Side note : You need to use this `$body = "Match: $match_name\n $check_msg"; ` as `$body .= "Match: $match_name\n $check_msg"; ` - concatenation

Comment: that seems to be a step in the right direction, I cannot post an image of how I recieve the email as I do not have enough reputation. It provides more than I had before, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HTML

<html>
<head>
<title>World Cup Challenge</title>
<style>
BODY{color:#000000; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Verdana}
.button {background-color: rgb(128,128,128); color:#ffffff; font-size: 8pt;}
.inputc {font-size: 8pt;}
.style3 {font-size: xx-small} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="mailer.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" size=""><br>
<br>

Brazil VS Croatia
<input type="hidden" name="match_name[]" value="Brazil VS Croatia">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="check0[]" value="Brazil">Brazil<br>
<input type="radio" name="check0[]" value="Croatia">Croatia<br>
<br>

Mexico VS Cameroon
<input type="hidden" name="match_name[]" value="Mexico VS Cameroon">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="check1[]" value="Mexico">Mexico<br>
<input type="radio" name="check1[]" value="Cameroon">Cameroon<br>
<br>   

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to         = "myemail@email.com";
    $subject    = "This is the subject";
    $name_field     = $_POST['name'];
    $i      = 0;

    $body       = "From: " . $name_field. "\n";

    foreach($_POST['match_name'] as $match_name) {

        $body .= "Match: " . $match_name . "\n";

        $check = "check".$i;

        foreach($_POST[$check] as $val) {

            $body .= "Selected Team: " . $val . "\n";       
        }

        $i++;
    }


    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {

        echo "Mail sent to: $to!";
    } else {

        echo "Sending mail failed";
    }

} else {
    echo "blarg!";
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesnt seem to be working. It returns the name, and it says the values of all the checkboxes (i selected brazil, and it return Selected: brazil, Selected: Cameroon) twice. Did you just add the "." like @shatheesh suggested?

Comment: @CGKeaton what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: There will be 50 total matches for the user to choose. I want the email to say, USERNAME at the top, then a break, MATCH TITLE #1 (Brazil VS Croatia), then the SELECTED TEAM(either brazil or crotia). After, I want MATCH TITLE #2(Mexico VS Cameroon), then the SELECTED TEAM(mexico or cameroon) for MATCH #2. Here is how it currently displays: http://i.imgur.com/3I3KDMG.png

Comment: @CGKeaton is it possible for you to change the name of the checkbox groups to check0[], check1[]

Comment: @CGKeaton is it like a match result prediction?

Comment: Yes it is selecting the predicted wiinner of the match! I can change those sure, but I'm a php-newbie - what will that do?

Comment: from a single match, the user can choose only one winning team right?

Comment: @CGKeaton please try the modified code, and check its working

Comment: you're a genius! it works beautiful and does exactly what I wanted! Last question, when it goes to the 'sent screen' it lists everything that has been sent (Ex. From: NAME Match: Brazil VS Croatia Selected Team: Brazil Match: Mexico VS Cameroon Selected Team: Cameroon Data has been submitted to mail@mail.com!) - Can I make this just say "Mail Sent - Thanks!" or something?